# How to Extract data from OSM within a polygon

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osmosis

Although I am a Openstreetmap's regular user for quite some time, I am pretty new to GIS, so I assume this is an easy question: I would like to know how can I extract data (eg: all schools) from OSM within a certain area defined by a polygon (eg: a city boundary or a city's neighbourhood) using QGIS.

### Extracting data

I have searched a bit about it and I found out (correct me if I am wrong) that there are different ways to perform queries on OSM, although I don't understand how/when do I have to use each one:

1. [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.44)
2. [Overpass](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)
3. [XAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Xapi)

### Using polygons

The problem is that as far (or as little) as I know all these methods rely on a square area, and I would like to know how can I do that within two types of polygons:

1. A city's boundary (this polygon exists in OSM, since is the one you see when searching for an specific city)
2. An arbitrary area, which would require to draw a new polygon using an external software (possibly QGIS? JOSM?).

Comment: How does QGIS fit with this data retrieval question? You can do the arbitrary area with http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Select_Region_by_Polygon but perhaps you need to ask a more specific question. Don't try to generalise - ask one direct question, and work from that to something more general later (either yourself, or via more questions).

Comment: you may want to extract schools from Overpass-api:
some schools are included as nodes, while others are areas (polygons or multipolygons), or both.
nodes, ways and relations  - All kind of objects

cf http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#All_kind_of_objects

Answer (score 5):

Overpass API allows you to extract by polygon:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Select_Region_by_Polygon

which should fill your needs.

You can use QGIS to draw the desired polygon, then extract the coordinates with the MMQGIS plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I decided to use [Quick OSM plugin](https://github.com/3liz/QgisQuickOSMPlugin), which allows you to make a query based on a territory name or a layer (which can contain vectors).